# OCR - Java - Find word edges from an Image

Tags: java, api, ocr

I'm working on an OCR Project which reads an image and finds the words 
in the image and slices them into small pieces where each piece will have a word.

Problem :
I want an OCR API ( Java , Open source recommended ) which find out word
edges for me. Is there anything available ?

I have already gone through Tesseract ( Tess4j) , JavaOCR.. But i couldnt find in 
these anything about finding exact word locations.

Please share your ideas & knowledge...

Comment: have you tried any image processing algorithms....

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @Pawal Sorry man, I dont want to start from there. I want to use existing libraries.

Comment: @limelights :) Thanks man, surely have that in mind IF i ask anything in future

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by finding the edges? For example you want to find the coordinates of the rectangle which a word will fit in that and output these coordinates?

As far as I remember from the `javaOCR` code, you can see the part that draws rectangles over your image file and find out where the coordinates of the rectangles are come from!

Comment: ya exactly. And after that, i want to seperate those "word pieces (rectangles)" into individual images. this is my concept. thanks for sharing your knowledge, i'll look into that part in javaOCR and will reply shortly